# Transform SVG group to create perspective ("trapezoid transform")

Tags: svg, transformation

Is there any way to create an SVG transform that would transform a square into an isosceles trapezoid to give the illusion of perspective?

I have a project ([visible here](http://sparks.staging.concord.org/sparks-content/activities.html#zzrrdmmoscope)) where I have one element group in the svg (the breadboard) that I would like to skew so that the bottom looks like it's a closer to the user.

I can transform the top-level SVG DOM element with a CSS transform (in supporting browsers) using something like "-webkit-transform: perspective(1000px) rotateX(40deg);", but this doesn't work in the nested group element.

Any suggestions appreciated, thanks!